# How can i do this kind of bottom nav bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter

[image: images]

please see this image above URL and give me a better solution for that.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/circle_nav_bar

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar. This package will help you achieve what you want.
Also, here a tutorial for that package: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrFc7W7MxzE